# PHP Multidimetional array breakdown

Tags: php

im trying to get to the data in this multidimetional array.

```
Array ( [return] => Array ( 
 [0] => stdClass Object ( 
  [array] => Array ( 
   [0] => ADMIN 
   [1] => http://www.adminpage.co.za/ ) ) ...
```

but when i try

```
$result = $array->return;
print_r($result);
```

i get

```
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in ... on line 10
```

if i try and call it as an array:

```
$result = $array[0];
print_r($result);
```

I get

```
 Undefined offset: 0 in ... on line 10
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`->` is an operator for objects, not arrays. Use `[]` on arrays. For example:

1. `$array['return']` will give you the array whose 0th element is
   `stdClass`
2. `$array['return'][0]` will give you the object
3. `$array['return'][0]->array` will give you the array whose 0th element is "ADMIN"

Answer (score 2):

This notice is absolutely fair. Array in php is not an object. You should access them as classic C arrays:

```
echo($myarr[2][3]);
```

Answer (score 0):

So from the given answers try:

```
print_r($array['return']);
```

Regarding to your edit:

you try to get the offset 0 in $array but there is no offset 0.
The offset you want is 'return'

```
$myarr = array( 'value1', 'value2' )

echo $myarr[0]
// 'value1'

echo $myarr[1]
// 'value2'
```

or:

```
$myarr = array( 'key1' => 'value1', 'key2' => 'value2' )

echo $myarr[0]
// Undefined offset: 0 in

echo $myarr['key1']
// 'value1'

echo $myarr['key2']
// 'value2'
```

Please read the [array manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) on php.net.